# Prepare SAS data to populate SQL Server temporary table, use that temp table to join with base sql server table in SAS EG

Tags: sql-server, sas, teradata

I have a scenario where I need to select data from a Teradata table in a database A. Use that result set to populate a SQL server temp table. This temp table needs to join with base SQL server table . The result set of this needs to be exported to another database table. Need to do it in SAS enterprise guide

This is my approach so far,
First create a SAS data set

STEP 1

```
proc sql;
  connect to teradata(user="abc" pw="def" database=cust fast load=yes mode=Teradata);
create table tmp_result as
select  from connection to teradata
(
SELECT 
Cust_id,
Name,
Product
 FROM Teradata table where ProductId=10
)DISCONNECT FROM TERADATA;
QUIT;
```

STEP 2

```
proc sql;
connect to odbc(dsn=temp user="abc" pw="def" connection=shared);
create table ##tmp
(
Cust_id int
Name varchar(100),
Product varchar(50);
)disconnect from ODBC;
QUIT;
```

STEP 3--insert data into temp table from first SAS data set

step 4
-create a base sql server table out of the below select query

```
SELECT *
FROM base sql server table join temp table (above temp table)
```

step 5
again create a sas data set out of above step 4 result set and then in final step

step 6
insert step 5 result set into a teradata table  database B.

I need help with my approach..I am still working on this solution but need your input if my approach is correct

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

You can do an implicit sql pass through by defining libname for your databases.

```
     libname teralib teradata server=myserver user=myuserid pwd=mypass;
     libname sqllib sqlsvr user=testuser password=testpass;
     libname saslib "somelocation"; /* you do not need this unless your manipulating 
   something in SAS*/

 proc sql;
 create teralib.yourotherteradatatable as
select a.id, b.col from sqllib.yoursqltable a
inner join teralib.yourteradatatable b
on a.yourinterstedcol = b.yourinterstedcol;
quit;
```

Comment: Thanks Rob and Kiran for your help. Got busy and forgot to thank. Better late then never;)

Answer (score 1):

*Depending on data volumes* Exporting from Teradata you will want either `TPT=NO FASTEXPORT=YES` or `TPT=YES FASTEXPORT=YES` to utilize the either the legacy FastExport or Teradata Parallel Transporter Export operator. The latter is preferred over the former if TPT is installed in your SAS environment. Pushing the data back to Teradata, replace `FASTEXPORT` with `FASTLOAD` or, depending on data volumes and TPT being available, consider `TPT=YES MULTISTMT=YES` which will utilize the Stream operator.

You approach will depend on how often this SAS workflow has to run, how many users will run this workflow, the data volumes being moved between the databases and SAS environments, and whether the SAS/Access interfaces are available for each database platform.

Hope this helps.